# Why does my gmod server only run locally?

Tags: steam, hosting, server-administration, garrys-mod

I am running Debian on my vServer. I have installed the Garrys Mod server using Steam CMD. I try to run it via

```
./srcds_run -console -game garrysmod +maxplayers +host_workshop_collection 252617757 -authkey ################################
```

It seems to start normally, the only thing weird is that it only runs locally. The last line it print while starting is

```
Network: IP 127.0.1.1, mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27015 SV / 27005 CL
```

Even if I add `-host domain.tld` or `-host 12.34.56.78` it will only run on localhost and cannot be reached by clients.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was, that it had problems parsing the server.cfg and therefore dind't found a map. You can fix it by either adding '+map ttt_mapname' to the command or 'map ttt_mapname' to the file.